# Fetching the column values from another table to create a new column in the main table : Pandas Merging with square brackets

Tags: python, pandas

As you can see below, I have two tables main table and reference table . In  the main table I have a column 'Subject' which contains tr_id within the '[]' separated by ',' . I have it to match with my reference table using the 'tr_id' to fetch the 'test_no' as 'Linked_Test_No' in my main table.

main table :

```
my_id    Name            Subject
12       Ash             The test [101 , 105]
15       Brock           The testing of the subject [101,102]
16       Misty           Subject Test [102,106]
18       Tracy           Subject Testing [101]
10       Oak             Test 
19       Paul            Testing []
21       Gary            Testing :  [107]
44       Selena          Subject : [104]
```

reference table :

```
tr_id      latest_em                                     test_no

101     pichu@icloud.com; paul@gmail.com                  120                            
102     ash@yahoo.com                                     130            
103     squirtle@gmail.com                                160
104     charmander@gmail.com                              180                              
105     ash@yahoo.com;misty@yahoo.com                     100
```

Currently, I am using `str.extract()` to fetch the tr_id and then using `pd.merge()`
to join two tables and then collating test_no into a single column "Linked_Test_no" which has lot of steps; can we achieve this with few lines of code; my coding skills are pretty basic.

Expected Output :

```
my_id    Name            Subject                                   Linked_Test_No
12       Ash             The test [101 , 105]                      [120,100]
15       Brock           The testing of the subject [101,102]      [120,130]
16       Misty           Subject Test [102,106]                    [130]
18       Tracy           Subject Testing [101]                     [120]
10       Oak             Test                                       
19       Paul            Testing []                           
21       Gary            Testing :  [107]                          
44       Selena          Subject : [104]                           [180]
```

Comment: Please show us the current code you are using.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Below code generate two columns for the linked score. One ignores the tr_id that not present in reference table (`df_s`) and another uses None if tr_id is missing. Use one according to your use case.

```py
# dict of id and score
s_map = df_s.set_index('tr_id')['test_no'].to_dict()

# extract subcode and store in list
df_m['Subcode'] = df_m['Subject'].str.extract('(\[.*\])', expand=False).apply(lambda x: [] if pd.isnull(x) else eval(x))

# fetch score from s_map 
df_m['Linked_Test_No'] = df_m['Subcode'].apply(lambda x: [s_map[xi] for xi in x if xi in s_map])

# similar to above line but it represent missing values in s_map by None instead of ignoring them
df_m['Linked_Test_No_alt'] = df_m['Subcode'].apply(lambda x: [s_map.get(xi, None) for xi in x])
```

[image]

Comment: Hi @user5828964 , I see what you did there. You've used dict of "tr_id" and "test_no" and then use lambda to map the values. Simple and efficient. Upvoted